# Powershell script to Find all VMs without a security tag and group

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have powercli module installed and cannot get powernsx to work no matter what I try, so I'm limited to direct API calls to NSX.

The goal is to report on all VMs that do not have a security tag applied.

I know i can see all VMs with Get-VM, and I can get all security tags calling https://10.x.x.x/api/2.0/services/securitytags/tag

That security tag call will only return the number of VMs it's applied to, and not the names. I need the names so I can compare to the output from Get-VM.

Does anyone know how to see the names of all the VMs that have security tags from NSX? The issue is sys admins spin up new servers and do not tag them. Need to see which ones are untagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this command helps you find what you are looking for, ([reference](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/574946))

```
Get-VM | Get-NsxSecuritytagassignment | select-object @{Name="SecurityTag"; expression = {$_.securitytag.name}}, VirtualMachine
```

Comment: Isn't Get-NsxSecurityTagassignment from the powernsx module?

Comment: It is from [powernsx module](https://github.com/vmware/powernsx/blob/master/deprecatedtests/sectagtests.ps1)

Comment: I cannot get the basic connection to work with the powernsx module. I have a whole other post on that one requesting help. I can access via native API calls though.

Comment: well.. thats going to get tricky for you real fast if you cant use the modules that gives you flexibility and performance. If you dont have access to nsx module, I dont know how you expect to get the name of the VMs. Security Tag Assignment is specific to NSX Managers and doesnt exist outside of that. vCenter itself doesnt know anything about it and unless you have a list of VM Names (somehow) that are part of that tag, there isnt any way to determine it.

Comment: I can hit NSX with API calls. I can also hit Vcenter with the powercli module. I can easily get all the VMs in Vcenter...but getting VMs without tags is my biggest problem. 

My thoughts are, run 2 commands (get-VM and whatever the NSX one that shows VMs without tags). Compare outputs, and show only the VM names that are different.

Comment: problem is: *whatever the NSX one that shows VMs without tags*. What i was hinting at was that it wont be possible unless you have a way to retrieve a list of all VM names via API call to nsx manager. If you do, you can use that list / csv to compare. Without it, its not going to be possible